# Salesforce inbound email to .msg attachment - Not opening in Outlook

Tags: apex, email, outlook

An inbound email is converted to the outlook .msg file and stored as an attachment to a record using handler class. Everything works fine, except I get this error when I try to open the file with outlook "Cannot start Microsoft Outlook. We can't open ..... It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it.
To check your permissions, right-click the folder, then click Properties." What am I missing?

```
Attachment.Name = attachmentname + '.msg'
ContentType ='application/vnd.ms-outlook'
body = Blob.valueof(email.plainTextBody)
```

Comment: did you got any solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on .msg files, but it seems that you need to do more than just declare the contenttype, change the name, and put the body into the attachment.

http://www.fileformat.info/format/outlookmsg/

Looks far more complicated.

Comment: Hey David, thank you so much for your time. Requesting one more favor from you if possible.. how about saving the file with .eml extension? I was able to open it up with outlook but the 'From' and 'Subject' were not shown. Is there anyway we can add that info for .eml extension?

Comment: It's all about researching the details of .eml files and then constructing that, somehow, within Apex. What you're talking about is similar to taking a .gif and trying to change the extension to .jpg and open it - or, more accurately, trying to change it to .xls and open it.

Comment: Any resolution on this problem?? I am facing the same issues.